# Using CONCAT to combine basic attributes like FirstName / Last Name

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I am pretty new to MYSQL, and have been struggling on getting Concat to work properly. I have tried several different variations found here, but without any luck. Can someone point me in the right direction on getting this to work. I am creating a very basic table and then a view to Concat the first and last name along with displaying the rest of the customer's information.

```
Create Table Customer(
CustomerId INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
FirstName VARCHAR(50), 
LastName VARCHAR (50),
 Address VARCHAR (75),
 City VARCHAR (50), 
State VARCHAR (50),
 Zip NUMERIC,
OrderID INT
);
CREATE VIEW CustomerInformation AS
SELECT FirstName, LastName, CONCAT(FirstName, ‘ ‘, lastname), 
Address VARCHAR (75),
 City VARCHAR (50), 
State VARCHAR (50),
 Zip NUMERIC,
FROM Customer
```

Comment: like this - `select concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) from t`?

Comment: (1) Use single quotes to delimit strings (as GurV showed above), and you should probably alias the CONCAT expression; 
(2) I don't recall VIEWs needing data type specifiers (at least not outside actual `CAST` operations).

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, CONCAT(FirstName, ‘ ‘, lastname), Address, City, State, Zip
FROM Customer
```

Do not add the column data type in the `SELECT` statement. That's only needed in the `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` statements